# Constructor of a struct copying a struct

Tags: c#

I have a struct which is for an Arc.

I created a constructor that accepts an Arc struct type and i want to basically copy the contents to the new struct i am creating but it seems to zero everything out - not sure if i am misunderstanding how this works.

This is what i have:

```
    //constructor, take an arc - copy it but with a new radius
    public Arc(Arc a, float radius)
    {
        this = a;
        a.Radius = radius;
    }
```

With the usage

```
        Arc arc1 = new Arc(arc0, arc0.Radius + _width/2f);
        arc1.Draw(Color.green,2);
        Arc arc2 = new Arc(arc0, arc0.Radius - _width/2f);
        arc2.Draw(Color.green,2);
```

For some reason `arc1` and `arc2` have default values for all its fields including the radius field.

I was expecting `arc1` and `arc2` to basically be copies of `arc0` but with a new radius.

Is the use of `this` not applicable for non reference types or something? I can't see why else i am having this problem.

Comment: Please post the full definition of `Arc`.

Comment: `a.Radius = radius;` - this does not do what you think it does. I suspect you are unfamiliar with value-type semantics in .NET.

Comment: @Dai ohhhh thats what it was ! Okay i made a stupid mistake ha! It works now! :)

Comment: I agree with Dai, surely you meant `this.Radius = radius`, not `a.Radius = radius`.  The latter modifies the argument only.

Comment: I heard you like structs, so we put a struct in your struct so you can struct while you struct. (I may or may not have had a beverage.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
    public Arc(Arc a, float radius)
    {
        this = a;
        a.Radius = radius;    // <-- This line is the problem
    }
```

Your use of `a.Radius = radius` means you're overwriting the `.Radius` member of **parameter** `a`, not **field** `this.a`.

Value-types, including `struct` values in .NET, do not share identity - whereas reference-types (`class` instances, `Object`, etc) can do (and do by default). So, with limited exceptions, you can think of each `struct`-variable as holding its own distinct copy of the entire structure instance.

Change your code to this:

```
    public Arc(Arc source, float radius)
    {
        this = source; // Copy `source` into `this`
        this.Radius = radius; // Then overwrite `this.Radius`
    }
```

Comment: Just a follow up question, if i had used `ref` in the constructor for `Arc a` would it share identity then ?

Comment: @WDUK I won't answer that. Instead I invite you to think about what the `ref` parameter modifier does and what "identity" means.